# convert video files to byte array in android

Tags: android

In my android application i am recording and saving the file in sdcard.
Now i would like to convert this saved file to byte array and sent it to the server.

Could anyone please let me know as how can i convert video files to byte array

Please forward your valuable suggestions.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Not knowing Android at all other than as a user, but a recorded video file is just a file... why the byte array?

Comment: This seems more like what you were looking for way back when:
[how-to-convert-files-to-byte-array-to-send-via-bluetooth-socket-in-android][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8614641/how-to-convert-files-to-byte-array-to-send-via-bluetooth-socket-in-android

Answer (score 1):

try this:

```
String strFile=null;
File file=new File(pathOnSdCard);
try {
byte[] data = FileUtils.readFileToByteArray(file);//Convert any file, image or video into byte array
strFile = Base64.encodeToString(data, Base64.NO_WRAP);//Convert byte array into string
} catch (IOException e) {
e.printStackTrace();
}
return strFile;
}
```